# python set object has not attribute append

Tags: python

I am working on a solving a maze with left hand rule and is working on counting on the number of steps taken to solve the maze but I am facing this error:

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Portion of the code:

```
steps = set()
def spriteDown(self):
        global steps
        if (self.heading() == 270):                   # checking if pointer is pointing down
            x_walls = round(sprite.xcor(),0)          # pointer x coordinates
            y_walls = round(sprite.ycor(),0)          # pointer y coordinates
            if (x_walls, y_walls) in finish:          # checking if pointer have finished the maze
                print("Finished")
                endProgram()
            if (x_walls +24, y_walls) in walls:          # checking  if they are walls on the left
                if(x_walls, y_walls -24) not in walls:   # checking if path ahead is clear
                    self.forward(24)
                    steps = steps.append(1)
                    return steps 
                else:
                    self.right(90)
                    return steps

            else:
                self.left(90)
                self.forward(24)
                return steps
```

Comment: I mean, you wrote `steps = set()` and then you try to do `steps = steps.append(1)`. It's unclear what you expect this to *mean*, but the `set` type indeed "has no attribute 'append'", like the error message tells you. I don't understand why you are confused, or what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set is not the correct choice for this program.

List should be used instead

```py
steps = list()
```

And also, it should be

```py
steps.append(1)
#instead of
steps = steps.append(1)
```

Also if the same value is inserted in a set more then ones it will only recognise it ones.i.e;

```py
set1={1,1,1,2,1,6}
#is same as
set1={1,2,6}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things (or probably 2)

1.
A set object has really no attribute 'append'.

2. You have some indentation issues.
3. Do we need set to solve this problem? (I am not confident about this statement).

Answer (score 0):

For a list of steps you need to take, you should not use Python sets.

They store the values, but the order is not kept and you can't have two same value in the set.

Sets use set.add instead of set.append, because there is no "end" of a set. Sets do not keep order.

I think what you want to do is to actually use a built in list.

```py
steps = list()
```

Comment: i changed the code and now theres a new error :

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You might want to try defining the list steps inside the function then. Don't use a global variable, since you're already returning it anyway.